# Will .asp suffix cause any issues

Tags: magento2, seo

**I have changed the suffix to .asp via the SEO section in Magento2 panel.**

**Although all pages & products are opening properly.**

> I wanted to know from your experience, will this cause any unexpected
>   issues? Like, Server trying to execute it as actual .asp page, or incompatibility with Magento's internal working

Answer (score 0):

If your webserver isn't set up to interprete ASP pages, this will not cause any issues.

Comment: So, I cannot use my current Windows VPS?

Comment: It depends on your IIS or Apache configuration. But actually, Magento does not support Windows, so you are better off using a normal Linux server

Comment: I have seen threads here related to using/installing Magento on IIS  https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=install%20iis

Comment: Yes, it might work, but it's not officially supported.

Comment: So, you are saying, on IIS (which interpretes ASP pages),  Magento will definitely have issues if suffix is .asp? And, on Apache/NginX (not set to inteprete ASP pages), there will be no issues if suffix is .asp?

Comment: I never said that. I just said that Magento does not support running on Windows, which has nothing to do with the webserver it's using. Also, a webserver - of any kind - that is configured to interprete pages ending on .asp - which is btw different from files ending on .asp - might cause problems when you end your pages with .asp.